# Entity framework association

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I could not figure the magic search words for this issue, so I shall ask.
Code first, entity framework 4.x

```
class Object1 
{
    // a reference to Object2, 3, 4, or 5
}

class Object2
{
}

class Object3
{
    private List<Object2> data;
}

class Object4:Object3
{
}

class Object5:Object3
{

}
```

How do I create Object1 such that it can contain an object that is either object2,3,4,5? Object1 would only ever reference one of these other objects

I have been playing with an abstract class, and shoving that into Object 1, but it get clunky when I expose a method to iterate the collection from Object3.

I am sure i am missing something obvious as this must be a common problem.

Per the first response, I tried to keep the question as simple as possible and left details out, so let me re-frame the problem by saying

```
class Object1
{
    public int i;
    public string something;
    public string somethingelse;
    // a reference to Object2, 3, 4, or 5
}
```

So it is not inheritance from Object1 and the other objects do not have those properties. Object1 unites other things, including one instance of Object 2,3,4,5... but only one instance

Answer (score 0):

Object1 class does not need to reference any other class. You can either have each class inherit from Object1 or you can make Object2 inherit from Object1, Object3 inherit from Object2 and so on. It depends on what you want to achieve.

In either case you will be able to pass ObjectX to an Object1.

```
public class Object1
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Object2 : Object1
{

}

public class Object3 : Object1
{

}
```

Then you can have something like this:

```
public void PrintAge(Object1 obj)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The age is: {0}", obj.Age);
}

var myObj = new Object3();
myObj.Age = 18;
PrintAge(myObj);
```